# octave/matlab: create new matrix based on existence of words from one matrix in another

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

In Octave/MATLAB, say I have:

```
all =
{
  [1,1] = one
  [1,2] = two
  [1,3] = three
  [1,4] = four
  [1,5] = five
  [1,6] = six
  [1,7] = seven
  [1,8] = eight
  [1,9] = nine
  [1,10] = ten
}

some =
{
  [1,1] = someword
  [1,2] = someword
  [1,3] = one
  [1,4] = someword
  [1,5] = nine
}
```

How would I make a new matrix such that

```
new =
{
  [1,1] = 1
  [1,2] = 0
  [1,3] = 0
  [1,4] = 0
  [1,5] = 0
  [1,6] = 0
  [1,7] = 0
  [1,8] = 0
  [1,9] = 1
  [1,10] = 0
}
```

that is, the `new` matrix has the same size as the `all` matrix, but the values are either `1` or `0`, depending on whether the words in `some` exist in `all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily with a for-loop:

```
new = cell(size(all));
for v=1:length(all)
    if any(strcmp(some,all{v}))
        new{v}=1;
    else
        new{v}=0;
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you could use intersect:

```
[isect, index_all, index_some]=intersect(all,some);
```

If you don't need your new values to be a cell (for zero or one, there's no reason not to use a simple array), then this is easy:

```
new=zeros(size(all));
new(index_all)=1;
```

If you need them to be a cell for some reason, then use:

```
new=num2cell(new);
```

PS: you should't use `all` as a variable name - it is an inbuilt Matlab function, and by overwriting it with a variable, you cannot use it until you clear the variable.

Comment: I used your first suggestion, it works great! Thanks man! Just a follow-up question.. If I have another matrix, called `some2`, and I apply the same for-loop to it to get the ones and zeros, how would I add it to the `new` matrix, so that now, the `new` matrix will have two columns - first contains 1s and 0s from `some`, the second contains 1s and 0s from `some2`?

Comment: You could generate a new2 output, and use `new_combined=new|new2;` to get non-zero values from both.

Comment: I get `error: binary operator '|' not implemented for 'cell' by 'cell' operations`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
new = ismember(all, some);
```

This returns an array. But if you want it in a cell array you can use

```
new = num2cell(ismember(all, some));
```

However, as Hugh Nolan mentioned in his answer, it is generally a good idea to avoid name of built-in function such as `all` as variable names.

Comment: That's a better answer than a for loop!